# Manners in electronic communication delays

Tags: communication, telecommute

My current employer is very distributed, over different countries. So all communication is via instant messaging.

People are very bad at getting back to you when asking for help.

How long should I allow somebody to answer before escalating or asking somebody else. Currently it is taking me up to 2 days to get answers to question that are blocking my work.

My work is such that I am only working on 1 thing at a time, so when I am blocked I am sat waiting, trying to research an answer etc.

Edit:
I have completely given up on email as I seem to have 0% chance of getting a reply to emails.

Edit 2:
Most people (including myself) seem to be third party contractors (out sourced), so there is no "team" to raise it with.

Comment: "_My work is such that I am only working on 1 thing at a time_" Who assigns you work? Is he in the same office/country/timezone?

Comment: He is in the same timezone, but other end of the country

Comment: Did you try **calling** him (or your solution source person) when you are blocked?

Comment: *"How long should I wait"* seems really specific to a given context. It will be a challenge to answer that. Have you raised this question with your boss?

Comment: Further: you state that all communication is by instant message, but then you basically say that IM isn't working for you. It sounds like you need to address the overall communication issue with your team/boss, not just determine how long you're supposed to wait.

Comment: The boss is the hardest person to get an answer out of, and then he seems to answer a completely different question.

Comment: Some people like IM, some prefer the phone, others prefer the email. You need to find out the persons preferred communication method

Comment: Personal opinion is that you shouldn't wait at all, if he/she doesn't answer you within 10-15 min you should look for help else where, I doubt boss will be mad at you for being resourceful and getting the job done

Comment: @SandraK no I honestly hadn't thought of that

Comment: You said your boss is in the same time zone, how about others? All in the same time zone?

Comment: @scaaahu everyone is in europe so within 1 or 2 hours of each other

Comment: If they are in the same time zone, I would wait about an hour and then call them on the phone. Be sure to state up front that this is blocking your work. If you are calling your boss, then ask him to assign you something else to work on when you are blocked.

Comment: VTC as company-specific:  How long is acceptable depends a lot on the circumstances.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instant messaging should be just that - instant

Check company policies and by-laws regarding peer-to-peer communication.

If nothing is set there 31 minutes :) , timezone specific, should be acceptable threshold.

IMHO, you cannot expect someone to answer you after-hours in his timezone